# sort possible options javascript array using fundamental counting principle

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, counting

I have 3 arrays which contains different values. and want get possible order options using.
I want to make a variation for my product, so when I select 3 variations, javascript will generate the possible sorting options.
eg:-

```
colors=['black','red','yellow'];
sizes=['s','m','l','xl','2xl','3xl'];
status=['used','new'];
```

```
let array1=['black','red','yellow'];
let array2=['s','m','l','xl','2xl','3xl'];
let array3=['used','new'];
var all=[];
all.push(colors.toString());
all.push(sizes.toString());
all.push(status.toString())
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    
console.log(option);
}
```

expecting:

```
[
    'black,s,used',
    'black,s,new',
    'black,m,used',
    'black,m,new',
    'black,l,used',
    'black,l,new',
    'black,xl,used',
    'black,xl,new',
    'black,2xl,used',
    'black,2xl,new',
    'black,3xl,used',
    'black,3xl,new',
    'red,s,used',
    'red,s,new',
    'red,m,used',
    'red,m,new',
    'red,l,used',
    'red,l,new',
    'red,xl,used',
    'red,xl,new',
    'red,2xl,used',
    'red,2xl,new',
    'red,3xl,used',
    'red,3xl,new',
    'yellow,s,used',
    'yellow,s,new',
    'yellow,m,used',
    'yellow,m,new',
    'yellow,l,used',
    'yellow,l,new',
    'yellow,xl,used',
    'yellow,xl,new',
    'yellow,2xl,used',
    'yellow,2xl,new',
    'yellow,3xl,used',
    'yellow,3xl,new',
    ]
```

I want to use product variation when a person chooses the 3 variations I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you calculate variations for your products

```
let colors=['black','red','yellow']; let
sizes=['s','m','l','xl','2xl','3xl']; let status=['used','new']; let
variations = [] for(let k=0;k<colors.length;k++){
    for(let i=0; i< sizes.length;i++){
        for (let j=0; j<status.length;j++){
            variations.push(`${colors[k]}-${sizes[i]}-${status[j]}`)
        }
    } }

console.log(variations)
```